# How to reclass zero values for an aspect raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster, reclassify, nodata, aspect

reclass in QGIS 3.4.11 to reclassify a raster file of aspect values. All cells reclass apart from zero values which now show as 'no data'. Text file is as follows:

```
0 thru 23 = 2
23 thru 68 = 2
68 thru 113 = 1
113 thru 158 = 1
158 thru 203 = 4
203 thru 248 = 4
248 thru 293 = 3
293 thru 338 = 3
338 thru 360 = 2
```

Comment: can you just change the nodata value to say -1 or 99999?

Comment: I need zero values to be reclassified to 2

Answer (score 2):

There seems to have been issues in GRASS's `r.reclass` tool for QGIS 3.4 according to [this bug report](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/28525).

I would suggest updating your QGIS 3 to the latest version and running the tool again. I can confirm it works on QGIS 3.8.3 for Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: I've updated to 3.8.3 64-bit and its still classifying zero values as no data

Comment: Version is 3.6.0 not 3.8.3

Comment: Don't use version 3.6.0. That's the first sub-version of an outdated version of the program. It will *definitely* have bugs. Use the actual latest version (3.8.3) or the latest long-term release version (3.4.12).

Comment: Thank you everyone. 3.4.12 now running and looking good